# STDIN redirection: how to make program end once fgets() reads an expected ending line

Tags: c, arrays, fgets, io-redirection

Ok, so I have a program that reads lines of a file. However once it reaches the line
`*** END ***`
it's meant to see that
`char str[100];`
`while(fgets(str,100,stdin) != NULL && strcmp(str,"*** END ***"))`
and the while loop should stop because strcmp will be equal to 0 therefore making the while loop false.

However it doesn't. I think this is because `str` has a different amount of chars (I'm assuming the rest after the copied line have nothing inside of them?) than `"*** END ***"`. How can I fix my program so that it will end once the line is read? Thanks.

OK, so I know now it's because in my example text, I had a line after that one. Once deleted it works fine. But how can I make it end whether there's a line after it or not?

Comment: might be because fgets appends `\n` sign to the str array if it finds it - hard to tell w/o the text source. Try removing empty lines after `*** END ***` char sequence in the text, or adding `\n` to the string you are comparing against

Comment: You are right. How can I make it work whether there's a next line after it or not?

Comment: You can use `strstr` like @user3365834 sugests in his answer

Comment: yeah, i see that either way does work

Comment: Hard to know what you are going for, but `strstr` also covers possibility of `*** END ***` inlined in other text like `This is the last line *** END ***`, but it probably is slower then `strcmp`, so I'd use `strcmp` if `*** END ***` will always occur alone in a single line, but `strstr` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
char * strstr ( const char *, const char * )
```

A pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of the entire sequence of characters specified in str2, or a null pointer if the sequence is not present in str1.

Answer (score 0):

I think your input terminates with an end of line (`\n`) character. `fgets` include that also in the string.

Try `strcmp(str,"*** END ***\n")` instead.

Comment: You are right. How can I make it work whether there's a next line after it or not?

Comment: one way is to use both conditions with `||`

Comment: I tried that but I don't believe it works.
In a while loop, true is any nonzero value. So if `str` is not null, that is true.
However now when we look at the right side, after the `&&`, we see that if we write
`(strcmp(str,"*** END ***") || strcmp(str,"*** END ***\n"))`
at this point I'm getting a little confused about the logic of the while statement, but I'm really hoping you see something else

Comment: So normally the right side would be any non-zero value because they arent equal. But if it reads one or the other conditions, then only ONE of those will be 0 in an `|| (or)` with a non-zero value. All that will be in an `&& (and)` with a 1. Therefore it will be non-zero... And that's meant to be false... right. So why isn't it working? I guess we want an AND with a 0. So I'll instead put an `&&` over here:
`(strcmp(str,"*** END ***") && strcmp(str,"*** END ***\n"))`